# how to bind multiple query in one gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a one grid view and three buttons. each and every button click i call stored procedure and bind the result in grid view. so i bind three query result on every button click. these three queries are different from others. Is it possible to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
add your gridview `aspx` page like:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ID="gvList">
</asp:GridView>
```

add these namespaces in your aspx.cs page.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
```

pass different different query from button click event.
and assign data source.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionstrin"].ToString());
 string spName= "StoreProcedureName";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(ds);
 if (ds != null)
 {
      gvList.DataSource = ds;
      gvList.DataBind();
 }
 else
 {
      gvList.DataSource = null;
      gvList.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: the three queries have 4 common field. that common field only displayed in gridview. example in 1st query i select 5 field value and 2nd query i select 6 field value and 3rd query i select 7 field value.  other field value is used to some purpose in code behind. how can i do this